# How to convert a cycle to not block a Tcl event loop?

Tags: multithreading, tcl, event-loop

I am writing a TCL/Tk application which at some point has a button that eventually runs the following loop:

```
    while {[llength $Queue]>0} {
        thread::mutex lock [tsv::set Workers Mutex]
        while {[tsv::llength Workers Available]==0} {
            thread::cond wait [tsv::set Workers Notify] [tsv::set Workers Mutex]
        }
        set tid [tsv::lpop Workers Available 0]
        thread::mutex unlock [tsv::set Workers Mutex]

        set Queue [lassign $Queue item]

        thread::send -async $tid "threaded_item $item"
        
        while {[tsv::llength Result Items]} {
            display_result {*}[tsv::lpop Result Items]
            update
        }
    }

    for {set i 0} {$i<$ThreadCount} {incr i} {
        thread::mutex lock [tsv::set Workers Mutex]
        while {![tsv::llength Workers Available]} {
            thread::cond wait [tsv::set Workers Notify] [tsv::set Workers Mutex]
        }
        set tid [tsv::lpop Workers Available 0]
        thread::mutex unlock [tsv::set Workers Mutex]
        thread::release $tid

        while {[tsv::llength Result Items]} {
            display_result {*}[tsv::lpop Result Items]
        }
    }
```

The `threaded_item` will run lengthy things and them append the result into `Result Items` TSV (thread shared variable), re-add itself into `Workers Available` TSV and sends a notification on the condition handle stored in `Workers Notify` TSV. `Queue` holds a whole workload split into shares, the first loop dispatched those shares to threads, the second loop drains the results for work dispatched last to each thread and releases them up.

This way I am able to parallelize the workload, and in principle it works. The problem is that loop blocks the application. I think it's because it is written with pthreads-style notification without thought of TCL's event loop. The place which blocks, I think, is `thread::cond wait`.

In attempts to resolve this I found an article [Update considered harmful](https://wiki.tcl-lang.org/page/Update+considered+harmful). In my case `update` it is definitely a hack for updated result appear on screen after `display_result` finishes, and its appearance looks like genuine example of bad design without event loop in mind.

So, I want to marry the notifications from threads with the event loop. I want to be able to pause/restart or interrupt and stop the process, and other things added. The question, how to do that? Should I run something in "after idle", if yes, what would it be? How to handle notifications from threads finished their share? How to handle the last pieces when the queue is drained and threads need to be released? How to guard against repeated starts of the process so already running jobs will be cleaned prior to dispatching new ones? Good would be to see an example/tutorial on how to rewrite such a process in an event loop-friendly way with TCL/Tk.

Comment: This is really a very good question! Are you using Tcl 8.6 or an earlier version? I ask because I suspect that a coroutine will be very helpful in disentangling this while still leaving it comprehensible.

Comment: I am not constrained, 8.6 is currently but probably it will be 8.7 when it's out. I tried to experiment with coroutines (outside of this topic, just for fun), would you explain how to use them for this case?

Comment: Did you consider using [`chan pipe`](https://wiki.tcl-lang.org/page/chan+pipe)s to implement communication between worker threads and the driver? As you rely on channel events, you are naturally marrying with Tcl's event loop. See the examples of thread notification at the bottom of the Wiki page (namely, the asynchronous signaler). I used this together with [thread pools](https://groups.google.com/g/comp.lang.tcl/c/LuM9kPm6ewQ/m/FdCFfN8IAgAJ) even, in the past.

Comment: I had to read that code a few times. It appears to be a thread pool! We've got one of those already.

Comment: @mrcalvin I did not know there was such a thing, thank you, I'll look. When I first met wonderful Tcl I/O it was the time 8.5 was in development, and I hadn't revised my knowledge since. Yet, threads are usually introduced as a way to avoid building communication pipes like this, so to some extent it defeats the purpose.

Comment: @NikitaKipriyanov I disagree, pipes are used to communicate and coordinate the threads, to avoid using conditional waits. The threads take the role of filters in a PIPES & FILTERS architecture, not system processes external to Tcl.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way forward when converting a looping construct into a form that doesn't block the event loop is *usually* to convert it into a coroutine. You can then replace the parts where you wait for something to happen with a `yield` where you've arranged for the resume of the code to occur when something of interest happens. As Tcl's coroutines are explicit constructs that have their own stacks, you do not need to mess around with function colouring (async/await in other languages) and can instead yield from inside a procedure called by the top level of the coroutine at whatever depth makes sense.

**In your case, however, you can do something else.** In particular, you appear to be reimplementing some sort of thread pool, and that's silly because [there's one already provided](https://www.tcl-lang.org/man/tcl8.6/ThreadCmd/tpool.htm); you don't need all that complexity of mutex locking and condition variables. Instead, you should use the existing pooling mechanisms and get the pool threads to post messages back to you when they're done with a work packet. Then you can just put all the work items into the queue and things will come back when they're done.

```
package require Thread

set pool [tpool::create -initcmd {
    proc threaded_item {item target} {
        # Do the computation here

        # Send a message back that we're done; messages are commands
        thread::send -async $target [list display_result "done with $item"]
    }
}]

foreach item $Queue {
    tpool::post -detached -nowait $pool [list threaded_item $item [thread::id]]
}

# Now just run the event loop and wait for things to be done
```

OK, the above code doesn't clean up the pool. If you're going to be reusing it (often a good plan in a long-lived application) then that isn't too big a deal, but if you're wanting to shut it down then you should instead schedule work to the pool differently:

```
set jobs [lmap item $Queue {
    tpool::post -nowait $pool [list threaded_item $item [thread::id]]
}]
```

And you can then clean up *when all messages back have been received* like this:

```
proc clearThreadPool {pool jobs} {
    while {[llength $jobs]} {
        foreach completedId [tpool::wait $pool $jobs jobs] {
            if {[catch {tpool::get $pool $completedId} msg opt] == 1} {
                # An error happened; print the stack trace
                puts stderr [dict get $opt -errorinfo]
            }
        }
    }
}

clearThreadPool $pool $jobs
# The next line deallocates the pool
tpool::release $pool
```

The "when all messages back have been received" above is best handled inside `display_result` and it can be just done by a counter of the number of times it has been called (versus the length of the queue of items). Remember that within a single interpreter, all code is strictly single threaded; inter-thread messages are done as events (the implementation of them is platform-specific) so the event loop must run to receive anything.

Comment: Yeah, sure, this is essentially thread pool. I've tried to use `tpool` at first attempt, but then I struggled to make it work at all. Each thread completed few shares and then failed with strange messages about some queue overflow. This way, with pool being implemented by myself, it at least worked.

Comment: Which Tcl version and Threads version are you running? Mind posting the concrete errors you caught?

Comment: Thread pools don't have max queue lengths that I'm aware of. I can't see anything like that in the [tpool source code](https://core.tcl-lang.org/thread/file?name=generic/threadPoolCmd.c&ci=tip) either.